# .Net TCP Client Communication Issue

Tags: .net, tcp, client

I'm new to network programming and was trying to establish communication between the ICE API test server and my application. The code below works only once, when I 'm trying to loging to the server. On the other words when I send my login message server replies to me with succesfull login. Once I get this, I send next message to the server, but in reply I'm getting 0, which means server already dropped connection. Can someone take a look on my client logic and point me to the right direction why the situation above happens. Please help me to resolve the issue since I'm already waisting days with no result. Thank you.

```
Public Function connect() As Boolean
            bConnected = True
            Dim port As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32("80") 
            Dim server As String = "63.247.113.201" 
            Try
                objClient = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(server, port)
                objClient.NoDelay = False
                objClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, 1)
                objClient.GetStream.BeginRead(byReadBuffer, 0, BYTES_TO_READ, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf doRead), Nothing)
            Catch ex As Exception
                RaiseEvent exErr(ex.ToString)
                bConnected = False
            End Try

            Return bConnected
        End Function

Public Function DoTCPRequest(ByVal data As String, ByVal resetSession As Boolean) As String 
            Dim objSw As IO.StreamWriter

            Try
                objSw = New IO.StreamWriter(objClient.GetStream)
                objSw.Write(data & vbCrLf)
                objSw.Flush()
                Console.WriteLine("Sent:" + data)
           Catch ex As Exception
                RaiseEvent exErr(ex.ToString)
            End Try

            objClient.GetStream.BeginRead(byReadBuffer, 0, BYTES_TO_READ, AddressOf Me.doRead, Nothing)
            Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byReadBuffer, 0, BYTES_TO_READ)
        End Function

      Private Sub doRead(ByVal ar As System.IAsyncResult)
            Dim nTotalRead As Integer
            Try
                Try
                    nTotalRead = objClient.GetStream.EndRead(ar)                     Catch ex As Exception
                    RaiseEvent exErr(ex.ToString)
                End Try

                If nTotalRead > 0 Then
                    Dim szReceivedString As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byReadBuffer, 0, nTotalRead)
                    RaiseEvent dataReceived(szReceivedString)
                    Console.WriteLine("Recv1:" + szReceivedString)
                End If

               objClient.GetStream.BeginRead(byReadBuffer, 0, BYTES_TO_READ, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf doRead), Nothing)     

            Catch ex As Exception
                RaiseEvent exErr(ex.ToString)
            End Try

        End Sub
```

Comment: I removed all comment and I hope now it makes more sense what I'm doing there. Could you please explain more what do you mean by this question 'Would you like to consider placing the BeginRead() inside doRead() in a condition?'. Thank you.

Comment: Okay. When the doRead gets the control. 1. First statement that gets executed is Steam.EndRead(). 2. Next statement is if nTotalRead has any number Show the received string on console. 3. Next statement is Stream.BeginRead() again. This means that the execution has to go on forever. It would never stop.

Comment: I guess this would not be what you need. By saying 'Would you like to consider placing the BeginRead() inside doRead() in a condition?', I meant you can avoid this infinite looping by placing a condition around the Stream.BeginRead(). The condition has to be something you need to define. May be for some finite amount of data, availability of data etc can be the condition. i.e IF nTotalBytesRecieved < 2048 Then objClient.GetStream.BeginRead(... kind of.

Comment: Thank you, SaravananArumugam, I tried that and I also tried Do... Loop While objClient.GetStream.DataAvailable for BeginRead in doRead function. Unfortunately, I have same result... only one reply from the server... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@lberezka, I see an odd thing in the code. Would you like to review the following line of code, inside DoRead() method.

```
objClient.GetStream.BeginRead(byReadBuffer, 0, BYTES_TO_READ, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf doRead), Nothing) 'Begin the reading again.
```

Ideally in any asynchronous call (Begin kind), the call back handle should receive the answer and try to end the call using End method. In your case Stream.EndRead.

What I see in your code is that you are recursively calling the begin method again and again and I don't see a EndRead anywhere.

Does it give you any clue?

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sorry for poor formating. My doRead function looks as follows.

Comment: Oh. Now I see the EndRead(). Great. But after executing EndRead, BeginRead is continued unconditionally. Is that what your intention is? Would you like to consider placing the BeginRead() inside doRead() in a condition?